# Creating Visual Studio Templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

I'm looking to create a Visual Studio 2008 template that will create a basic project and based on remove certain files/folders based on options the user enters.

Right now, I have followed some tutorials online which have let me create the form to query the user and pass the data into an IWizard class, but I don't know what to do from there.

The tutorials provide a sample to do some simple substitution:
code:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
DialogResult dlg = form.ShowDialog();
if (dlg == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in form.Parameters)
    {
        if (!replacementsDictionary.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
            replacementsDictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        else
            replacementsDictionary[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
    }
}
form.Close();
```

but I'm looking to selectively include files based on the user settings, and if possible, selectively include code sections in a file based on settings.

Is there a clever way to do this, or will I manually have to delete project files in the IWizard:ProjectFinishedGenerating()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, `ShouldAddProjectItem` only gets called for *folders* in the template project. As such, it's pretty much useless.

Instead, you would need to put code in your `ProjectFinishedGenerating` implementation that uses the VS API to remove ProjectItems.

In there, you can remove items like this:

```
ProjectItem file = project.ProjectItems.Item("File.cs");
file.Remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can selectively include parts of a file by using `$if$` with replacements. See, for example, this bit in the default C# Class Library template:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System"/>
    $if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)
    <Reference Include="System.Core"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions"/>
    $endif$
```

...etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to determine whether or not you should add project items to a project.

If so, you can implement IWizard.ShouldAddProjectItem and return whether or not you want the file to be added or not.

Comment: This is very helpful, but I would also like to know if its possible to selectively include parts of a file based on settings.

The answer you provider here though is great. Thank you.